# How to define a hashmap with contents in 1 line in Rust?

Tags: rust

I can use `vec![1,2,3]` to build a vector.
Can I build a hashmap in Rust a bit like this:

```
hashmap![("key", "value")]
```

without creating a separate variable and calling `.insert()` each time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you create a macro

```
macro_rules! hashmap {
    ($( $key: expr => $val: expr ),*) => {{
         let mut map = ::std::collections::HashMap::new();
         $( map.insert($key, $val); )*
         map
    }}
}
```

then you call it like following

```
let map= hashmap!["key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"];
```

Answer (score 11):

One solution is to rely on an array and `collect()` it into a `HashMap`:

```
fn main() {
    let map: std::collections::HashMap<_, _> = [("foo", 0), ("bar", 1)]
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

It outputs:

```
{"foo": 0, "bar": 1}
```

[`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) From the Rust documentation:

> Transforms an iterator into a collection.
>
> collect() can take anything iterable, and turn it into a relevant
>   collection. This is one of the more powerful methods in the standard
>   library, used in a variety of contexts.
>
> The most basic pattern in which collect() is used is to turn one
>   collection into another. You take a collection, call iter() on it, do
>   a bunch of transformations, and then collect() at the end.

Comment: It would be better not to use the vector to avoid unnecessary memory allocation. The array works fine with cloneable types: `[("foo", 0), ("bar", 1)].iter().cloned().collect()`

Comment: Yes. It's corrected.